# Generating Machine Keys programmatically with .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, iis

I'm working on an ASP.NET website deployment utility and I need for the custom installer to be able to generate secure machine keys the same way that IIS's interface does.  Is this possible using first-party capabilities in .NET?

I'm looking for a native .NET based solution, not powershell or command
line.  .NET 4+ IIS 7+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I used it, but I think this should work:

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] argv)
{
    int count ; 
    if ((argv.Length == 0) || !Int32.TryParse(argv[0], out count))
        count = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var keyConfig = GetASPNET20machinekey();
        Console.WriteLine(keyConfig);
    }
}

public static string GetRandomKey(int bytelength)
{
    byte[] buff = new byte[bytelength];
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    rng.GetBytes(buff);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytelength * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++)
        sb.Append(string.Format("{0:X2}", buff[i]));
    return sb.ToString();
}

public static string GetASPNET20machinekey()
{
    StringBuilder aspnet20machinekey = new StringBuilder();
    string key64byte = GetRandomKey(64);
    string key32byte = GetRandomKey(32);
    aspnet20machinekey.Append("<machineKey \n");
    aspnet20machinekey.Append("validationKey=\"" + key64byte + "\"\n");
    aspnet20machinekey.Append("decryptionKey=\"" + key32byte + "\"\n");
    aspnet20machinekey.Append("validation=\"SHA1\" decryption=\"AES\"\n");
    aspnet20machinekey.Append("/>\n");
    return aspnet20machinekey.ToString();
}
}
```